# Netlogo: Can one access a turtle variable with a concatenated word?

Tags: variables, attributes, concatenation, netlogo

I have edited the code to focus on the issue:

```
    globals [num_periods]
breed [observeds observe]

observeds-own [potential0 potential1 potential2 potential3 potential4 potential5 potential6 potential7 potential8 potential9
 ]

to setup
clear-all
reset-ticks
   ask patches [set pcolor white]

  create-observeds 1 [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor  set shape "square" set color green 
  set potential0 random 0 set potential1 random 0 set potential2 random 0 set potential3 random 0 set potential4 random 0
  set potential5 random 0 set potential6 random 0 set potential7 random 0 set potential8 random 0 set potential9 random 0
    ]
 
end

to go
  ask observeds [
    let test1 (word "potential" who)   ;; this should output potential0 a variable 
      let test2 runreport [test1] 
   print test1  ;;prints potential0
   
    ask observeds with [test2 = who][
      move ]]  ;; trying to move the turtle 

end


to move
right random 360
fd 1
end
```

As there is only one agent it's who = 0. I have set all of the variables potentialx, x = [0,9], to zero. I have then 'created' the word 'potential0' by concatenating the work potential + who of the agent. Then I have asked all  agents with potential0 to move and nothing happens.

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: I am a bit confused about your goal and about what the code is trying to do. Can you try to create a very minimal example of the problem? Something that reproduces the problematic behaviour while also getting rid of anything that is not strictly necessary

Comment: `random 0` is always 0, so I'm not sure what you are doing there.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use `runresult` for this.
`runresult` takes whatever string it is applied to and treats it as a reporter rather than a string. If that string contains a number it returns a number. If it contains a variable name, it treats it as a variable.
So the following should solve your problem

```
    ask observeds with [runresult test1 = who][
       move 
    ]
```

Comment: Hi Leirs, I have restated the problem - I am adding the last digit based on the who of the agent, not trying to extract it. Thanks, Kevin

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what you are trying to do here. You are checking for each turtle if their who (a number) is equal to a string. This is never the case because these are different data types.

Comment: But `runresult` might be the solution here as well. As I said in my answer, `runresult` takes a string and turns it into a reporter. A variable name is also a reporter.

Comment: Hi Leirs, The turtles have an attribute called 'potential0' I am trying to get those agents with potential0 = 0 to move. If I type in 'with [potential0 = 0]' it works. However if I instead form  potential0 by joining potential with 0 (using the word function), such as let test1 word(potential" who) [where who = 0] , whilst print test1 outputs potential0,  the ask function '...with [test1 = who] doesn't work. Even though test1 = potential0 and who = 0

Comment: I have edited the code to incorporate your suggestion. It's still not working - I added let test2 runreport [test1], then made the ask [with test2 = who]. Looking at the netlogo directory I think I have the format of runreport correct.

Comment: UPDATE Got it to work. the trick is to have runresult (word "potential" who) - ie not use the string. Thanks very much for your help. Kevin

Comment: That's weird. I just copypasted your code and it worked when I pasted my solution in there

Comment: Maybe because you wrote runreport instead of runresult in your edited code

Answer (score 1):

Use let test1 runresult (word ("potential" who) to form the string potential0. Subsequent commands will then recognise this as a reporter